# Liquid's concat filter not working on arrays from shopify metafields?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template, shopify-liquid

Liquid's `concat` filter works like a charm using it on self-created arrays or arrays from section settings. However, I cannot get it to work when using it on arrays from metafields of a shopify product.

I have two metafields on my products: One holding a list of products and one holding a list of product variants. The types of the metafields are `list.product_reference`
and `list.variant_reference`. I want to merge both lists:

```
{%- assign products = product.metafields.custom.fcv_products.value -%}
{%- assign variants = product.metafields.custom.fcv_variants.value -%}
{%- assign items = products | concat: variants -%}
```

However, `items` will be `null`. When outputting this expression in the console like this:

```
<script>console.log({{ products | concat: variants | json }})</script>
```

I get the following error: `Liquid error (sections/...): concat filter requires an array argument`

Both arrays contain elements. The following logs all work as expected:

```
{%- for variant in variants -%}
  <script>console.log({{ variant | json }}); // Prints variants from the list </script>
{%- endfor -%}
<script>console.log({{ products | json }}); // Prints an array with products </script>
<script>console.log({{ variants | json }}); // Prints an array with variants </script>
<script>console.log({{ items | json }}); // Prints null </script>
```

Prior to this solution using the metafields, I used something similar to the following, which worked perfectly fine:

```
{%- assign products = section.settings.products -%}
{%- assign variants_nested = products | map: "variants" -%}
{%- assign variants = "" | split: "" -%}
{%- for variants_list in variants_nested -%}
  {%- assign variants = variants | concat: variants_list %}
{%- endfor -%}
{%- assign items = products | concat: variants -%}
```

Because of changed requirements we have to switch to the metafields solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your **metafield type** defined in Shopify ? Is it **list.product_reference** or something else ?

Comment: @BilalAkbar Yes, the types are `list.product_reference` and `list.variant_reference`. I added them to the description.

Comment: **list.product_reference** and **list.variant_reference** are not simple array. They are list and concat filter does not work on them. In the JSON filter you can see the values, because JSON filter internally iterates over the list.

What are you looking to achieve with concat ? I may be able to suggest some solution then. Like iterating over these 2 lists separately and creating an array or json.